# How to auto log the events in facebook event manager using react native facebook sdk?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk-next

I'm using [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next) for the logging events. Custom events which I have created works fine for Android and iOS. But in case of **Subscribe** auto logged event I can see that only iOS events are logged. I've went through the documentation but I didn't find anything useful. Also in facebook event manager I can see that **Auto logging Event** is saying **unspecified** there are also **on** and **off** for the auto logging event. Am I missing something here? I don't want to mess with existing events and their settings because I'm using this in production. I want to enable the **Auto logging** event for **Subscribe** event.